# Download any file from the browser by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application by clicking a button any extension of file can be downloaded.
From the backend I am getting the filePath ,filename.
Now in my frontend controller I am getting the response and trying to download file in the following way.
But it is not working.

```
myService.getExistingFileFromserver($scope.fileId)
.then(function(response){
  var link=document.createElement("a");
  link.download=response.data.filename;
  link.href=response.data.filePath;
  link.click();  

 },function(response){
console.log('failure');
  });
}
```

Please suggest where I am doing mistake.

From the backend I am returning an object as response.

Comment: Can you provide the error message you have encountered. Have you tried append `link` to `body` and click it manually? Also, can you provide code of you backend as well?

Comment: @DoanVanThang I am not getting any error .Getting a blank tab . Actually the file is coming from unix server.